# Problema con loop tipo while (Py)

Tags: python, bucles

estoy programando algo que me guarde datos en un diccionario y quiero que el usuario ingrese sexo masculino o femenino. La solución que plantié fue la siguiente:

```
paciente['sexo']=input('Sexo del paciente (masculino o femenino): ')
while paciente['sexo'] != 'masculino' or paciente['sexo'] != 'feminino':
    paciente.pop('sexo')
    print('Respuesta no válida. Ingrese nuevamente el sexo del paciente, masculino o femenino')
    paciente['sexo']=input()
```

Si el input es diferente de masculino o femenino, se iba a borrar dicha entrada y mostraría un mensaje el cual le pediría corregir la respuesta. Pero cuando ejecuto, aunque ponga la respuesta correcta al inicio, siempre va a ocurrir ese bucle:

```
Sexo del paciente (masculino o femenino): masculino
Respuesta no válida. Ingrese nuevamente el sexo del paciente, masculino o femenino
masculino
Respuesta no válida. Ingrese nuevamente el sexo del paciente, masculino o femenino
femenino
Respuesta no válida. Ingrese nuevamente el sexo del paciente, masculino o femenino
```

Supongo que es un problema con el bucle...

Comment: `paciente['sexo'] != 'masculino' or paciente['sexo'] != 'feminino'` si es distinto de masculino o distinto de femenino? Esa condición siempre va a ser true puesto que nunca la misma variable va a poder valer 'masculino' Y 'femenino' a la vez! La condición correcta en ese caso, sería `paciente['sexo'] != 'masculino' and paciente['sexo'] != 'feminino'`, mientras que la variable sea diferente de masculino **Y** femenino, es decir, no es ninguno de los dos!

Answer (score 3):

**Lo que está mal**

Como bien te apuntó GBianchi, tienes un problema lógico en la comparación que haces en el `while`. Pudieses sustituir tu condición actual con la condición que él te sugirió, o con la siguiente:

```
while paciente['sexo'] != 'masculino' and paciente['sexo'] != 'femenino'
```

**Lo que se puede mejorar**

Aparte del problema ya mencionado, puedes mejorar tu código al menos de las siguientes tres maneras:

1. Evitando repetirte a ti mismo: Estás haciendo dos veces casi exactamente la misma línea, que es cuando pides el `input()` al usuario. Puedes tener un ciclo `while` infinito y adentro del ciclo hacer la petición, para así evitar tener que pedir el input antes del ciclo como tal. Luego con la condición adecuada, solo llamas a `break` para romper el ciclo.
2. Usando adecuadamente el diccionario: Los diccionarios son hash tables. Debido a esta naturaleza, cada key debe ser única. O sea, si ya estás añadiendo la key `'sexo'`, no necesitas sacarla haciendo `pop` para luego volverla a introducir. El comportamiento por default del diccionario hará que se sobrescriba el valor anterior que tenía esa `key`.
3. Usando un chequeo de membresía: En vez de hacer el concatenamiento de dos condiciones que son muy similares (`paciente['sexo'] != 'masculino' and paciente['sexo'] != 'femenino'`) un enfoque más *Pythonic* es el de chequear si en un iterable dado se encuentra el valor que quieres (en tu caso `'masculino'` o `'femenino'`) usando la keyword `in`. Incluso, puedes hacer una constante que contenga esos valores y así hacer el código más legible.

**Cómo yo lo haría**

```
SEXOS = ('masculino', 'femenino')

while True:
    sexo = input('Sexo del paciente (masculino o femenino): ')
    if sexo in SEXOS:
        paciente['sexo'] = sexo
        break
    print('Respuesta no válida. Ingrese nuevamente el sexo del paciente.')
```

Comment: Una pregunta ¿Ese in que está en el condicional es como compara dos veces osea como poner el AND y comparar otra vez?

Comment: Considero esta respuesta de baja calidad, por que no es más que solo código.

Comment: Eso basicamente mira si es igual a cualquiera de las cosas que le pases dentro de la tupla (puedes usar una lista también en vez de una tupla), y puede tener tantos valores como quieras, no solo 2.

Comment: @Gabitohh Si darle downvote te hace sentir mejor, chévere, La respuesta no será una biblia acerca del uso de ciclos infinitos, ni plantea un debate entre usar el chequeo de membresía (`in`) vs. concadenar condiciones, pero soluciona y responde el problema del OP.

Comment: @revliscano Yo no le dí -1

Comment: Ten en cuenta cuando respondas, que tu respuesta sea completa... eso quiere decir que no sea solo codigo, si no que expliques lo que hace el mismo. Algo que puede ser obvio para vos, puede no ser tan obvio para otra persona que lee tu respuesta...

Comment: Vale, fe de errata. Actualizaré mi respuesta con más detalle... De cualquier manera el downvote es injustificado. La respuesta dada no es ni peligrosa, ni off-topic, ni spam, ni conlleva a errores o malas prácticas. @gbianchi

Comment: yo tampoco te vote negativamente... pero los votos no significan eso, solo significan, como lo dicen los tooltips de los botones, si la respuesta es util o no...

Answer (score 1):

El problema es totalmente logico...

Si vos escribis masculino, y deshacemos tu codigo, veamos que pasa:

```
paciente['sexo'] != 'masculino' => true
paciente['sexo'] != 'feminino' => false (ojo aca tenes un typo)

true or false => true
```

Entonces, lo que vos queres es que en realidad las dos cosas al mismo tiempo sean falsas, porque si una es verdadera, para vos ya es verdadero... entonces, lo mejor seria un xor, ya que si las dos son falsas va a dar verdadero, si las dos son verdaderas (Que es imposible) va a dar falso

Entonces, xor esta definido como != (segun [esto](https://stackoverflow.com/q/432842/73749))...

asi que lo que vos queres hacer, seria algo como

```
not ((paciente['sexo'] != 'masculino') != (paciente['sexo'] != 'femenino'))
```

Comment: O lo que sería igual, usando `and`:  `paciente['sexo'] != 'masculino' and paciente['sexo'] != 'femenino'`